# objeto não funciona dentro de função avulsa

Tags: php

boa noite.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura php

```
<?php
  require_once("testaAdmin.php");
  require_once("../_global/_erros/erros.ini");
  require_once("../_controlls/_util/Constantes.php");
  $constantes = new Constantes();

  if (isset($_POST["acao"]) && $_POST["acao"] == "cadastrar") {

  ......
function comparaArrays($array1, $array2) 
{
   if(is_array($array1) && count($array1) > 0) {
       $i = 0;
       foreach($array1 as $value1) {
           foreach($array2["name"] as $key =>$value2) {
               print $value2."<br>";
               if ($value1 == $value2) {
                   if ( $array2["error"][$key] == 0) {

                       $extensao = pathinfo($value2, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
                       $nomeFoto = md5(uniqid(time())).".". $extensao;

                       move_uploaded_file($array2["tmp_name"][$key], "../".$constantes->getEnderecoNormal()."/".$nomeFoto);

                       $fotosDao->cadastrar ($imoveisDao->ultimoIdCadastrado(), $nomeFoto);
                   }
                  $i++;
                  break;                                 
               }
           }
       }
   }
}

$arquivos1 = explode ("|", $_POST["arquivos"]);  
$arquivos2 = $_FILES["fotos"];

comparaArrays($arquivos1, $arquivos2);
.......
  }
 ?>
```

Tenho a construção `$constantes->getEnderecoNormal()` na linha do `move_uploaded_file` que o php me retorna que o objeto não existe se colocado dentro da função. Mas se colocado fora da função funciona.

Onde estará o erro?

Alteração da função conforme alteração:

```
///////////////////////////UPLOAD DAS FOTOS////////////////////////////////////
function comparaArrays($array1, $array2, $imoveisDao, $constantes, $fotosDao, $ultimoIdCadastrado) 
{
   if(is_array($array1) && count($array1) > 0) {
       $i = 0;
       foreach($array1 as $value1) {
           foreach($array2["name"] as $key =>$value2) {
               if ($value1 == $value2) {
                   if ( $array2["error"][$key] == 0) {

                       $extensao = pathinfo($value2, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
                       $nomeFoto = md5(uniqid(time())).".". $extensao;   

                       move_uploaded_file($array2["tmp_name"][$key], "../".$constantes->getEnderecoNormal()."/".$nomeFoto);

                       $fotosDao->cadastrar ($ultimoIdCadastrado, $nomeFoto);
                   }
                  $i++;
                  break;                                 
               }
           }
       }
   }
}

$arquivos1 = explode ("|", $_POST["arquivos"]);  
$arquivos2 = $_FILES["fotos"];

comparaArrays($arquivos1, $arquivos2, $imoveisDao, $constantes, $fotosDao, $imoveisDao->ultimoIdCadastrado());
////////////////////////////UPLOAD DAS FOTOS////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem a questão é que você está misturando programação orientada a objeto com estruturado *(mágica que "só o PHP" permite e é duramente criticada, eu particulamente gosto desde que seja bem feito)*, de forma simutaneas lado a lado, porém desse jeito não rola bem, imagine que uma função do PHP seja um 'casulo' os dados de foram não entra e os de dentro não sai, um não se passa para o outro de forma 'normal' assim podemos dizer, para entender todo o processo tera que estudar [OOP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_a_objetos) e [Programação estruturada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_estruturada) a fundo para entender o por que de tudo isso. Então o que digo agora é que para se resolver isso AGORA você tem 3 soluções.

**1)** Você passa seu objeto pela função, ou seja na assinatura da sua função:

```
<?php
$constantes = new Constantes();

function comparaArrays($cons, $array1, $array2) {
 // Código ...
 move_uploaded_file($array2["tmp_name"][$key], "../".$cons->getEnderecoNormal()."/".$nomeFoto);
 // Código ...
}

// Código ...
comparaArrays($constantes, $arquivos1, $arquivos2);
?>
```

**2)** Ou você torna a sua váriavel global em toda a função:

```
<?php
$constantes = new Constantes();

function comparaArrays($cons, $array1, $array2) {
 global $constantes;
 // Código ...
 move_uploaded_file($array2["tmp_name"][$key], "../".$constantes->getEnderecoNormal()."/".$nomeFoto);
 // Código ...
}

// Código ...
comparaArrays($arquivos1, $arquivos2);
?>
```

**3)** O terceiro jeito é iniciar a classe dentro da própria função:

```
<?php
function comparaArrays($array1, $array2) {
 $constantes = new Constantes();
 // Código ...
 move_uploaded_file($array2["tmp_name"][$key], "../".$constantes->getEnderecoNormal()."/".$nomeFoto);
 // Código ...
}
// Código ...
comparaArrays($arquivos1, $arquivos2);
?>
```

Comment: Várias outras linguagens além do PHP permitem, como C++, Harbour, e quando bem usado, é ótimo. O problema da pergunta é relacionado a um erro de programação apenas. Não tem nada de errado em usar cada paradigma onde for melhor. Concordo com o seu "eu particulamente gosto desde que seja bem feito". O problema é que geralmente o pessoal tem cabeça muito fechada pra sair das "rédeas" da instituição/curso/influência onde aprendeu, então não mistura paradigma pq é "pecado" kkk.

Comment: @Bacco coloquei umas aspas no "só o PHP" pq estamos falando dele nesse tópico, foi mais uma licença poetica no texto do que de fato so ela fazer isso, como por exemplo posso citar o JavaScript que faz essa mistura tbm e eu adoro também. E eu tbm não acho errado usar desde que saiba o que esta ocorrendo.

Comment: Bom, adicionei ao corpo da pergunta a nova estrutura da função e gostaria de saber a opinião de vocês quanto à alteração

Comment: **Bem a questão é que você está misturando programação orientada a objeto com estruturado (mágica que "só o PHP" permite e é duramente criticada** Isso para mim é novidade.

Comment: É porque essa função só se encaixa nesse contexto e é apenas ela nessa situação. Caso eu coloque ela dentro de uma classe de utilitários por exemplo, não dará para ser usada pelo fato de seu desenvolvimento ser bem peculiar. Mas resolveu. Obrigado!

Comment: Carlos, seu problema foi resolvido? Se sim, defina como melhor resposta e evite que outros percam tempo tentando responder!
Quanto à questão de opiniões próprias sem fundamentos em estudos, na programação eu aconselho evitar ao máximo, vendo que o melhor é saber usar cada ferramenta/método em sua hora.